# How to match all characters inlcuding new lines in between two words using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

for example I have something like:

```
OLD

WHO IS THIS

END?

On Sun, 22 Sep 2019 at 23:57,
```

I'd like to capture everything from the beginning till `\n\nOn Sun,`
so my expected outcome would be:

```
OLD

WHO IS THIS

END?
```

I tried doing the following pattern: `^(.*)\n\nOn .* wrote:` which only works if the text I need doesn't contain new lines. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Why not  `^((.|\n)*)\n\nOn .*` or add `flags=re.DOTALL` to your call to `re.search()` - try reading the documentation e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html

Comment: @barny: `(.|\n)*` - please forget this pattern, it's one of the worst possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for Regex try this:

```
text = """
OLD

WHO IS THIS

END?

On Sun, 22 Sep 2019 at 23:57,
"""

text = '\n'.join(line for line in text.split('\n') if line.startswith('On Sun'))
print(text)
```

Output:

```
OLD

WHO IS THIS

END?
```

Comment: I think using `startswith()` will be more appropriate than `'On Sun' not in line`.

Answer (score 0):

The direct translation would be

```
^OLD.+?(?=^On Sun)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/DaaD2p/1/) (mind the multi- and singleline flags).